# J2ME image rotation

Tags: java, java-me

In j2me there are no methods to rotate an image by arbitrary angles(25,30,etc). I refered and tried with the following link. It works fine on emulator,but in device the response time is very slow..

[J2me Image Rotation](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?206189-J2me-Image-Rotation&p=764607&viewfull=1#post764607)

How to fix this issue? or are there any other ways to rotate an image smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

refer this link.I hope it may help you
 http://code.google.com/p/j2me-imageviewer/downloads/detail?name=J2MEImageViewer-autorotate.jad